# Extracting data from a find_element query (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So I'm trying to extract certain data from within a find_element search

```
quest1 = browser.find_element_by_id("a29081363")
quest1.title = browser.find_element_by_class_name("title").text
quest1.desc = browser.find_element_by_class_name("desc").text
quest1.progress = browser.find_element_by_class_name("progress").text
```

How do I make the title, desc and progress only search within the data from "quest1" rather than the whole website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `find_element_by_*` methods on the `quest1` [element](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) instead of on the `browser`:

```
title = quest1.find_element_by_class_name("title").text
desc = quest1.find_element_by_class_name("desc").text
progress = quest1.find_element_by_class_name("progress").text
```